# SSAS Reporting Services - Set specific language / translation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssas

in the data warehouse there's a default language for the measures, and I added a translation for German captions. In a Visual Studio Report Server project, when creating a query with my German OS, the cube and its measures are displayed in German language. When dragging measures to the mdx query windows, the default measure name (English) is used. That's what I expect, since when writing MDX queries I would like to use the default measure names. But when executing the query, the columns of the query result created for each measure are translated to German again. This resuls in having German columns names within my dataset, which I dont want. I'd like to have the default (English) column names.

I already tried to change the connection string to: Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=DataWarehouse;LocaleIdentifier=1033

But that doesn't help, I still see German translations.

Anyone knows how to set a specific translation?

Probably I now answer my own question:

This is what I found on the internet.

"Locale Identifier  The LCID specified MUST be supported by the operating system on which the data source object resides."

Does that mean I have to have the English language pack installed on my XP machine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sounds like you need the english lang pack on your machine, since you are on a German OS